# Regex a phrase to uppercase the first word

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not a expert in regex, but i think this can be done with regex. What i wanna do is, i have this phrase

> I WANNA CONVERT THIS PHRASE

and i want to convert to

> I Wanna Convert This Phrase

The first character from each word goes to uppercase.
How can i do this in regex?

Is in C# language

Comment: Regex alone cannot be used to manipulate a string in this way. What language / platform are you using?

Comment: You would need a blind search and replace `\b(\w)(\w*)\b`, replace with `toupper(grp1)+tolower(grp2)`, or something like that. What language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, convert the entire string to lowercase:

```
var input = "I WANNA CONVERT THIS PHRASE";
input = input.ToLower();
```

Then you can use a regular expression and a lambda function to get get things done:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b\w", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The regular expression `\b\w` matches a word character just after something which isn't a word character, which should indicate a start of a word normally.